# reading from istringstream slower than ifstream

Tags: c++, performance

I'm trying to read point cloud file (PTX). I tried 2 solutions in order to do that:

The first one : The most easy method. `std::ifstream` and `getline(...)` while I can read.
 The second one : I read everything and put everything in a `std::istringstream` then read from this using `operator >>`.
Since I put everything in memory with the second method, I tought reading from it would be faster but no.
In average : 45 seconds for method number 1 and 49 for number 2.

Here are my codes :
Method 1:

```
std::istringstream getLine(std::ifstream& file) {
    std::string line;
    std::getline(file, line);
    return std::istringstream{ line };
}

void readPoint(std::ifstream& file, TinyPTX& tptx) {
    std::vector<PointPTX> ptxPoints(tptx.numPoints);

    size_t num_pts_to_remove = 0;
    tptx.asCol = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < tptx.numPoints; ++i) {
        float x, y, z, intens;
        uint8_t r, g, b;
        getLine(file) >> x >> y >> z >> intens >> r >> g >> b;
        PointPTX& _pptx = tptx.cloud->points[i - num_pts_to_remove];
        if (!isZero(x, 10e-4) || !isZero(y, 10e-4) || !isZero(z, 10e-4)) {
            _pptx.x = x;  _pptx.y = y; _pptx.z = z; _pptx.intensity = intens;
            _pptx.r = r;
            _pptx.g = g;
            _pptx.b = b;
        }
        else
            num_pts_to_remove++;
    }
    tptx.numPoints -= num_pts_to_remove;
    tptx.cloud->points.resize(tptx.numPoints);
}
```

Method 2 :

```
bool readPoint(std::istringstream& str, TinyPTX& tptx, std::streamsize& size) {
    std::vector<PointPTX> ptxPoints(tptx.numPoints);

    size_t num_pts_to_remove = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tptx.numPoints; ++i) {
        float x, y, z, intens;
        int r, g, b;
        str >> x >> y >> z >> intens >> r >> g >> b;
        PointPTX& _pptx = tptx.cloud->points[i - num_pts_to_remove];
        if (!isZero(x, 10e-4) || !isZero(y, 10e-4) || !isZero(z, 10e-4)) {
            _pptx.x = x;  _pptx.y = y; _pptx.z = z; _pptx.intensity = intens;
            _pptx.r = r;
            _pptx.g = g;
            _pptx.b = b;
        }
        else
            num_pts_to_remove++;
    }
    tptx.numPoints -= num_pts_to_remove;
    tptx.cloud->points.resize(tptx.numPoints);

    int pos = str.tellg();
    std::cout << pos << " " << size;
    return pos > size - 10 ;//Used to know if we're at the end of the file. 
}
```

My question is : why is the version in which I put everything in memory slower than the other? Is there something I'm missing? I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't change multiple aspects when comparing performance. Compare `getline` for `ifstream` vs `istringstream` or compare `getline` vs `operator >>` for the same stream.

Comment: I recommend that you really make `readPoint` take a reference to `std::istream` as then you could use *any* input stream (files, strings, even `std::cin`).

Comment: @grek40 I will do the try. Thanks
Some Programmer Dude: Yes, I just understood that my function getline was useless and I could use every stream

Comment: how are you measuring the speed? have you run the code multiple times? are you using an optimised build? Which platform are you using? We need a [mcve].

Comment: I'm using Visual studio 2017. I'm not sure I'm using an optimized build, but I'm using the same for the 2 functions, (release x64).  I'm mesuring time using clock_t.   
And I did the test several times, and the results are always like I said before

Comment: better to use ifstream's `.read(buffer, big_number)` and then read from there.This all depends of cache policy

Comment: I use `std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
  std::streamsize size = file.tellg();
  file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

  std::vector<char> buffer(size);

  size_t cpt = 0;
  if (file.read(buffer.data(), size)) {
   std::istringstream stream(&buffer[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something I'm missing? I'm doing wrong?

It only makes sense to create an intermediate `std::istringstream` for each line if your would like to ignore the rest of the line.

If all lines contain just these 7 values you can read them directly from `std::istream& file` (instead of `std::ifstream& file`). I.e. change:

```
getLine(file) >> x >> y >> z >> intens >> r >> g >> b;
```

to:

```
file >> x >> y >> z >> intens >> r >> g >> b;
```

Comment: I'll take a look at this solution. But isn't it supposed to be faster to put everything in RAM, and then work on it, instead of reading line by line from a file?

Comment: You might want to emphasize that the changed code most likely will fail if the input is malformed.

Comment: @RaphSchim If you read an entire file into a `stringstream` first that involves multiple memory allocations and copying when growing its content buffer, unlike if you read directly from `ifstream`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I tried the 2 solutions, read directly from ifstream and generate a stringstream. 2 options are similar considering time consuming :( ...   
SomeProgrammerDude you're right. But since it is needed to be read by other product, my file should nev er be malformed :/ Otherwise I wouldn't be able to work on it

Comment: Should I use a  `std::vector<char>` instead of a `std::istringstream` and then work on this vector?

Comment: @RaphSchim I don't think so.

Comment: well, ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**The first method is slower !**

I ran your code on a short sample (20k lines) and the performances I did observe are :

- first method :

  - 1004 ms total
  - 1004 ms in the readPoint method
  - 553 ms in the std::getline method (inside the readPoint method)
- second method :

  - 101 ms total
  - 56 ms in the readPoint method.
  - 54 ms in the ifstream::rdbuf method (outside of the readPoint method)

Of course I had to write the code that read the file and put it in istringstream in the second case, and performances of the second method really depends on how you built your istringstream.

What I suspect is that a part of your issue is out of the code you show here.

**Why is it ?**

The main reason why the first method is much slower is because of what Maxim Egorushkin explained to you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52854500/7490633) .

But even if you spare all that unnecessary wrapping you do, it is anyway, because files operation are buffered, and a single call on ifstream::rdbuf is faster than multiple call to >> opreator.

Unfortunately, this second method will become really slower if, for some reason, you lack memory.

Using the code suggested by Maxim Egorushkin I had those results :

- 310 ms total
- 305 ms in the readPoint method

Regards,